# Events filtering with OR operator

Tags: web3js, events, filters

I want to get all user's transactions from ERC20 compatible tokens.
I can get all incoming transactions using this code:

```
const to = token.Transfer({_to: account}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
transferEvent.get((_, transactions) => { console.log(transactions); });
```

But how can I get all transactions (incoming and outgoing) using web3 interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you may pass only one [filter object](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) per query and there are no higher order logical operators like sum or intersection available.

I'd recommend querying for events twice (first for incoming, then for outgoing) and merge the results using sth like [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp). A good token implementation should prevent self-sending so there shouldn't be duplicates, but obviously, it's best to check for that as well.